# How can I call a SaltStack module with a list of arguments

Tags: saltstack

Given the following function in a SaltStack module called `salty`, how do I sent a sequence to the `event` function  for the `tags` argument, that is `tags` should be a Python list:

```
def event(name, desc, tags=None):
    assert type(tags) == list
```

I expected the following to work but it doesn't:

`salt-call salty.event myname mydesc tags=tag1,tag2,tag3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
salt-call salty.event myname mydesc tags='["tag1","tag2","tag3"]'
```